# ZFS and Permanent errors - what does it mean?

Tags: zfs

I need a little help with a problem. I have a raidz1 pool:

```
    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
data1       DEGRADED     0     0     0
  raidz1-0  DEGRADED     0     0     0
    sda     ONLINE       0     0     0
    sde     DEGRADED     0     0     0  too many errors
    sdd     ONLINE       0     0     0
    sdf     ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)
  mirror-1  ONLINE       0     0     0
    sdb     ONLINE       0     0     0
    sdc     ONLINE       0     0     0

    errors: Permanent errors have been detected in the following files:

    data1:<0x8a33>
    data1:<0x2b33a>
    data1:<0x2922f3>
    /data1/hd1/TaskImage.bin
```

Before I restarted the system, drive sdf was FAULTED. The READ Counter was at 25. Short time later the sde drive was DEGRADED. Currently I run zpool clear on the pool. And it's resilvering.

Well, ZFS show errors on the /data1/hd1/TaskImage.bin file. It's a 3TB drive Image. This is a "nice to have" file. If I want, I can get the file entirely back from the original drive. But I don't care that much. It's going to be ok for me, if I have the files, and some parts of the file are corrupt.

My current plan is to rebuild the whole pool. So I got a 10TB drive and would like to send the ZFS filesystem to another pool. Can I do it in this state?

Answer (score 0):

```
zfs send
```

will fail when it encounters an error, so you will need to remove any damages files before you take a snapshot you intend to send.

Test using:

```
zfs send pool/fs@snap > /dev/null
```